# unable to find .war file in tomcat webapps folder

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7

configured new Ubuntu server things were going good

deployed my application through tomcat manager

things are up and running im able to access my application also

but i'm unable to find my war file in webapps folder 
documents tel me that war file will be present in webapps folder only

Any idea will be great

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Open conf/server.xml and see which directory is used in the "appBase" attribute from the "host" element.

Comment: Maybe you have two different Tomcat installations? What is inside your webapps folder?

Comment: Indeed, answered same day ;)

Comment: I did a mistake  installing tomcat twice one in /home/Ubuntu/tomcat one more was some where near /var ... finaly I figured it out by searching the name tomcat in directorys 's